# Random double and gaussian distribution

Tags: java, evolutionary-algorithm

I want to generate double numbers [-25,+25] but it does not work for me!.
I used this code :

```
//=============== method set random individuals  (genes)======================
public void rand_gene() {
     double rand = new Random().nextDouble();
    for (int i=0 ;i<size;i++) {
        this.setGene(i, -25+(rand));
    System.out.print(genes[i]+"  ");
        } }
```

and I want to round it to 2 numbers after coma.

any help ?

Comment: You want a Gaussian distribution? What you're generating is a uniform distribution. Also, Gaussian is not bounded, so do you want a truncated Gaussian distribution? Finally, what do you mean by "round it to 2 numbers"? Do you mean that you want the values to be selected from {-25.00, -24.99, -24.98, ..., +24.98, +24.99, +25.00}?

Comment: I'm generating a normal distribution for evolutionary strategy algorithm , and yes I meant [-25.00,....,+25.00 ]

Comment: How do you want to deal with the infinite tails of a normal distribution? Do you want to just truncate at +/- 25? What mean and standard deviation do you want for the distribution? (I'm assuming 0 mean, but if you're truncating, then there's no info at all here about standard deviation, and no guarantees about the mean, either. Please provide the full details of what you need.)

Comment: I'm trying to code the evolutionary strategy (1+1) ES that means generating a random vector r with ri~ N(0, sigma^2) for i in [1, n]  using sphere fitness function sum xi^2 , my range is +/-25.

Comment: I already created random vectors with nextdouble(), and I want to associate each vector to another random vector containing sigma with nextGaussian() respecting the range

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental problem with your code is that you are generating a single random value and using it for all `i`. But your code has other problems as well.

A Gaussian (a.k.a. normal) distribution has infinite tails, so if you want the random variable to be restricted to [-25, +25], it can't be a Gaussian distribution. The typical approach is to use a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution). There are several libraries that generate such random variables, which you can find with a web search. I'd start with a look at the [Stochastic Simulation in Java](https://github.com/umontreal-simul/ssj) library, or perhaps [Broadwick](http://epicscotland.github.io/broadwick.html) (in particular their [`TruncatedNormalDistribution` class](http://epicscotland.github.io/Broadwick/jacoco/broadwick.statistics.distributions/TruncatedNormalDistribution.java.html)).

A poor-man's approximation is to use a simple sample-reject algorithm with a normal distribution generator, as below.

The other issue—that you want values rounded to 2 decimal places—is easily accomplished by multiplying by 100, rounding to the nearest integer, and then dividing by 100.

Here's my take on doing what you want:

```
// initialize a random number generator
// for production work, consider using a better RNG than java.util.Random
private Random rng = new Random();
private double sigma = /* desired standard deviation */

public void rand_gene() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        setGene(i, nextRand());
    }
}

/** Return a random Gaussian in the range [-25, +25] */
private double nextRand() {
    double val;
    do {
        val = sigma * rng.nextGaussian();
        val = Math.round(val * 100) / 100.0;
    } while (val < -25 || val > 25);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: thx for replying , but I'm still confused about what I'm doing, knowing that  
I'm trying to code the evolutionary strategy (1+1) ES that means generating a random vector r with ri~ N(0, sigma^2) for i in [1, n] using sphere fitness function sum xi^2 , my range is +/-25. Is the code about adabt with my algorithm?

Comment: @Nori - Well, it sounds like the code I suggest here should be used to generate the random vector _r_. (That's assuming that `setGene(i, value)` sets the `i`-th component of _r_ to `value`.) Each element of the result will be approximately N(n, sigma^2), truncated to +/-25.

Comment: great , my question seems silly but  what about sigma?  why we have to assign it even though the nextGaussian method do it randomly I geuss !! In my case how could this  `val = sigma * rng.nextGaussian();` affect on my sphere function ? )

Comment: @Nori - The value of sigma determines how narrow or wide the peak of the distribution will be. Even with truncation to +/-25, the distribution can vary widely. With a very large sigma, the values might be almost uniformly distributed in the range. With a very small sigma, the values might very rarely fall outside a much narrower range around 0. See the [Wikipedia article on the 68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) for more info on how sigma affects the values you should expect to see after calling `rand_gene()`.

Comment: @Nori - I should mention that the 68-95-99.7 rule doesn't actually apply when dealing with a truncated distribution. I only refer you to it because it provides an excellent starting point for thinking about how the truncation range and sigma will interact.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification, I want to know how can I choose the value of sigma because it influences dramatically on the mutation strategy  of my EA to get the optimal solution of the benchmark sphere function !

Comment: @Nori - I don't know enough about ES to provide any guidance there. I suggest you just experiment with different values. A smaller sigma will, as I understand it, result in a lower probability of dramatic mutations (and vice versa, of course).

Comment: I noticed that the round method does not work as we expected , its generete always integer value with the code you offered me. `/** Return a random Gaussian in the range [-25, +25] */
private double nextRand() {
    double val;
    do {
        val = sigma * rng.nextGaussian();
        val = Math.round(val* 100) / 100.0; // this line should round 2 decimals dont you !
    } while (val < -25 || val > 25);
    return val;
}`

Comment: @Nori - Sorry, but it's hard to read extensive code in comments. I'm well aware that `Math.round()` returns an integer value. That's why I multiplied by 100 before rounding and divided by 100.0 after rounding. That's a standard trick for rounding to the nearest 0.01. (It's important to divide by a `double`, not the `int` literal `100` or else you'll get integer division, which is not what you want.) You're getting integer values with my code?

Comment: Sorry for the unreadable code in comments , and yes your code generate integer values. How can we fix it to get double nearest 0.01 results?

Comment: I'm apologize to disturbing you with my mistake, I rounded two times that why its generate integer values,   it works pretty well right now. Thx  a lot @Ted Hopp

Comment: @Nori - Okay! Glad you found the problem.